# Google Cloud Dataprep: add file parameter metadata as column value

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I want to ingest a GCS folder full of files which all have the date in the filename like `/foo_2018-08-22.txt` and `/foo_2018-08-23.txt`. For each file I'd like to add the date of the data (from the filename) as a value in a column such that all rows which come from the first file are labelled as 2018-08-22 and so on.  I know how manually to do this for individual files, but is there any way to do so for an entire file full of files?  I played with "parameterized datasets" but can not figure how to pull out the value of those identified parameters into formula values.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no automatic way of doing this for entire folder. However, there is an open [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/74386476) for it to be implemented. You can add your input on the thread and/or click on the star to receive notifications for any updates.